# How to multiply within a filter method in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I am trying to make it so that the value at every even index is  multiplied by 2. It's not multiplying by two. I don't understand why.

```
const testArray = [1,3,4,5,6];

const skipDigitFunc = testArray.filter((num, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    return num * 2;
  } 
})

console.log(skipDigitFunc);
```

Comment: Use the `.map` method. Also, if using filter, add an `else` condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct an array which is one-to-one with the input array, so use `.map` instead:

```js
const testArray = [1,3,4,5,6];

const skipDigitFunc = testArray.map((num, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    return num * 2;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
})

console.log(skipDigitFunc);
```

More concisely:

```js
const testArray = [1,3,4,5,6];
const skipDigitFunc = testArray.map((num, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? num * 2 : num);
console.log(skipDigitFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of filter will return only the actual value, when some piece of code is executed successfully, so treating that.

`2*2 = 4` assuming true so it's returning 2 if you multiple `0*2=0`, then it's 0 treating false then it'll not return anything.

```
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

const newArr = arr.filter((value)=>value*2)

console.log(newArr) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: because of autocorrecting some of the symbols is changes 

2*2 = 4 and 0*2 =0